# Getting back to monogame game page from xaml page. (Windows Phone 8.1 runtime)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, monogame

I have created a separated xaml page for my game where I will show the global submited highscores. I am using monogame library for my game and I am expecting some problems navigating through game page and the new xaml page.

I have successfuly worked out how can I navigate user to the xaml page where highscores are shown, using this code:

```
var frame = new Frame();
frame.Navigate(typeof(SubmitScoreDialog)); //SubmitScoreDialog the xaml page
Window.Current.Content = frame;
Window.Current.Activate();
```

The problem I am expecting is when I want to navigate the user back to monogame Game Page with all the graphics that have to be drawn are not there... I just got a black screen, and I can't do nothing. The code I used to navigate user back from xaml page to monogame game page is almost the same as the one above:

```
var frame = new Frame();
frame.Navigate(typeof(GamePage));
Window.Current.Content = frame;
Window.Current.Activate();
```

What can be the problem that my graphics are not drawn ... ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm completely missing the question here, but... Why not just use the standard page navigation provided by Windows Phone?

Comment: And which is the standard page navigation? I GamePage.xaml is the standard game page, and SubmitScoreDialog is the second xaml page, and I have problems navigating back to gamepage.

Comment: This should get you going: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: The problem is not navigating itself through pages. I know how to do that. The problem is that my game is not resuming (nothing is not drawn, black page) after I return from another xaml page to monogame game page....

Comment: Oh, wait you're using the latest stable monogame build, right? I mean the one that you download and install from their website.

Comment: Yeah, 3.3 if I am right ... Windows Phone 8.1 template.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work. I don't know why not, but it doesn't. So it's not as "Stable" as they claim. I had the exact same problem when I tried to create a WP game. I ended up pulling the current source from Github and using that. That works. Using an older build would also work I think.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a solution for my problem. **@Bjarke Sogaard** if you want to fix also your problem. Change in App.xaml.cs in OnLaunched event with the following code:

```
//Declare this variables up in the app.xaml.cs class
public GamePage GamePage;

//In OnLaunched:
var app = App.Current as App;

// Create a main GamePage
if (app.GamePage == null) app.GamePage = new GamePage(string.Empty);
// Place the GamePage in the current Window
Window.Current.Content = app.GamePage;
Window.Current.Activate();
```

Then, put this code, to navigate from the game page to xaml page:

```
var frame = new Frame();

frame.Navigate(typeof(SubmitScoreDialog));

Window.Current.Content = frame;
```

Then to navigate back to game page (in my case in SubmitScoreDialog.xaml.cs):

```
var app = App.Current as App;

// Create a main GamePage

if (app.GamePage == null) app.GamePage = new GamePage(string.Empty);
Game1.statics.graphics.SupportedOrientations = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight | Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
// Place the GamePage in the current Window
Window.Current.Content = app.GamePage;
```

I have to mention that this will not fix 100% the problem. You can navigate from game page to a xaml page, and then back. But when you do it again, the game exits... And I don't know why at the moment...